# Invalidate queries, how to pass a variable (React Query)

Tags: reactjs, react-query

When I execute `onSettled` within `useMutation` I want to pass a string.

In the beginning, I'm passing a string called `top` as the `pageType` but once I executed `onSettled`, I want to pass a different value  (lottery) in the `pageType`

I want to do modify is the value('top' -> 'lottery') in the variable `page`  in the `` get(`/api?token=${token}&page='top'` ``  -> `` get(`/api?token=${token}&page='lottery' ``

I tried `onSettled: () => queryCache.invalidateQueries(['campaign', {pageType: 'lottery'])` but that didn't work.

Any idea how can I do it?

useCampaign:

```
const useCampaign = (token, id, page) =>
  useQuery(
    'campaign',
    () =>
      instance
        .get(`/api?token=${token}&page=${page}`, {
          headers: { 'id': id }
        })
        .then((res) => res),
    {
      retry: false,
    }
  )
```

index:

```
const { data } = useCampaign(
    token ?? '',
    campaignID ?? '',
    'top' // here the value needs to be 'top'
  )

const [lottery, lotteryInfo] = useMutation(
    () =>
      instance.post(
        ENDPOINT,
        {},
        {
          headers: { 'id': campaignID }
        }
      ),
    {
      onSettled: () => queryCache.invalidateQueries('campaign')
// here I want to pass the value of 'lottery' instead of 'top'
    }
  )
```

Note: I'm using React Query 2.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Add page to your query key

```js
const useCampaign = (token, id, page) => {
    return useQuery(['campaign', page], () => {})
}

// Later in your useMutation

onSettled: () => queryCache.invalidateQueries(['campaign', 'top'])
```

Comment: Apologies, I didn't explain myself. What I want to do modify is the variable `page`  in the ```get(`/api?token=${token}&page='top'` ``` -> ```get(`/api?token=${token}&page='lottery'```

Answer (score 0):

`invalidateQueries` is not the right choice here. What you essentially want to do is update the pageType so that you can fetch some different data. This means the query keys should ideally be different. Here's how you can do that.

useCampaign:

```
const useCampaign = (token, id, page) =>
  useQuery(
    ['campaign', page],
    () =>
      instance
        .get(`/api?token=${token}&page=${page}`, {
          headers: { 'id': id }
        })
        .then((res) => res),
    {
      retry: false,
    }
  )
```

index:

```
const [pageType, setPageType] = useState('top');
const { data } = useCampaign(
    token ?? '',
    campaignID ?? '',
    pageType
  )
const [lottery, lotteryInfo] = useMutation(
    () =>
      instance.post(
        ENDPOINT,
        {},
        {
          headers: { 'id': campaignID }
        }
      ),
    {
      onSettled: () => setPageType('lottery')
    }
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it works but only on the first request. If I do another request the data is not being updated, any other way to fix it?